# Custom filter criteria for sitecore xConnect Provider for Data Exchange Framework

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework

We have a requirement for filtering out the Sitecore `xConnect` contacts who have visited the site in the last 24hours. These data needs to be synced to a `Salesforce` custom object using `Data Exchange Framework`. However, we don't know how to configure the filter expression for this.

It would be of great help, if someone can provide me some pointers on how to configure the same, or some links which explains about how to configure `DEF`.

Thanks for your time.